# Arduino or Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, arduino-uno

I'm making a robotic dog. I want it to bark, follow you via beacon in your hand and ultrasonic sensors like eyes and can be controlled via bluetooth/wifi. Which should I choose for control : Arduino or Raspberry Pi? It will have at least 5 servos, so I think I will need two motor controller boards.I don’t have much money, so I must find something inexpensive and I don’t know which alternative of controller will be cheaper. I know basics of C++ but don’t know Python. Sorry for my English , I'm not from US/UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino is a simple embedded platform that can be used for control applications as you have described. It is likely to lack processing power when compared to Raspberry Pi but for simple control applications should be more than able. There are add on shields to control most hardware and even Bluetooth and WiFi connectivity. Programmig is usually performed on a computer using the Arduino IDE which uses a form of C/C++.

The Raspberry Pi is more like a mini computer with a full Linux operating system. You would require an add-on boards to allow you to control devices but the latest Pi (the Raspberry Pi 3) includes WiFi and Bluetooth on-board). You can program by connecting a keyboard and monitor then using Python, scratch, C, even ARM Assembly or pretty much any language you can use on Linux. You can even connect a camera and program it to track an object.

I would usually think an Arduino for simple control, Raspberry Pi for more complicated applications.

Comment: http://kproapps.com/arduino-vs-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 1):

[SEE RASPBERRY PI VS ARDUINO COMPARISON](http://makezine.com/2015/12/04/admittedly-simplistic-guide-raspberry-pi-vs-arduino/)

Arduino is better for beginners.

If you know what you are doing, I think the Raspberry Pi is the better option here.

You can find information about a similar project "Erica the Rhino" developed with Raspberry Pi. [Erica the Rhino Documentation](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/397340/1/erica.pdf)

Comment: http://kproapps.com/arduino-vs-raspberry-pi/